# Android recycleView (with cardViews) crashes with many elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I'm working on implementing cardView on my Android application. I Followed the official tutorial and then adapted it to my fragment class, everything worked fine. Then i added my custom cardView with images (that I previously save to local storage) and if my card list is too long my app would crash with this log.

```
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:923)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(ViewCompat.java:1343)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.addViewHolderToRecycledViewPool(RecyclerView.java:3900)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleCachedViewAt(RecyclerView.java:3843)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:3880)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleView(RecyclerView.java:3804)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleViewAt(RecyclerView.java:5529)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:1139)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleViewsFromStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.recycleByLayoutState(LinearLayoutManager.java:1244)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1268)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1102)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:959)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1047)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:1768)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7205)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2231)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2237)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2151)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1480)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2435)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2099)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7385)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3331)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4422)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4401)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
03-24 11:24:07.917: E/AndroidRuntime(20763):    at android.view.InputEventRece
```

I've been searching, but I could not find any answers to my question.
I'm testing on 2 devices Lollipop and pre-lollipop and the same happens, sometimes the Lollipop device can handle a bigger list (5 items with image), but it crashes when i add more cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. 
I needed to update compatibility libraries v4 and v7

Comment: How? Please post the solution so others can see too.

Comment: Download the latest version from the package manager and make sure you are referencing the latest version on your gradle dependencies